# How do I overwrite X bytes on offset Y with fwrite()?

Tags: c, file-io, fopen, overwrite, fwrite

All I can find using fopen() and fwrite() in C is to delete all contents and start writing again or append to the end of the file. What if I need to go to some offset in the file and overwrite a few bytes?

Is that possible with some function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can open the file with the `"rb+"` option and then use `fseek` with `SEEK_SET` to go to a specific location.  The`rb+` opens it for both reading and writing as a binary file (the file must exist in order for it to succeed - it will not create a new file).

Comment: That will overwrite just the bytes I want and will not append?

Comment: The question is, will it discard the remainder of the file beyond what you've written?

Comment: @Nazgulled: Yes - the SEEK_SET positions to a specific byte offset in the file.  SEEK_CUR can also be used to seek to an offset from the current location.

Comment: @Joe:  No, it will leave the remaining data unchanged.